# Using windows authentication for a Django app served by linux box

Tags: python, django, security, windows-authentication, django-settings

I have Windows users that access a Django app that runs on a linux server. The question was asked, can that Django app use windows authentication to verify users? Or is it impossible since Django runs on a linux server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to your question is, "it depends." There are several different kinds of Windows Authentication, and it depends which you are using.

If you're logging into a company domain using Active Directory, then yes, you can use the same authentication for Django. I use a package called `django-python3-ldap`, which supports Active Directory; you can find it here:

https://github.com/etianen/django-python3-ldap

You'll have to work with your Microsoft Windows domain administrator to get the settings correct for your Active Directory LDAP server. Active Directory is Microsoft's brand name for its flavor of LDAP.

On the other hand, if you're using a local computer account, the answer is no, and if you're using a Microsoft Live account, the answer is... it's complicated!

Good luck.

Comment: Thanks! You've given me a great place to start.

Comment: I could really use your advice on another question I asked today. I've worked with django-python3-ldap and I'm on the brink of success but I keep hitting a wall. [My other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59001155/find-users-of-security-group-with-django-python3-ldap)