# Find users of security group with django-python3-ldap

Tags: python, django, ldap, ldap-query

*Very* new to LDAP and AD. I'm using django-python3-ldap to authenticate users of my django app.
We want to make it so that only a subset of our users can access our django app, so yesterday they added the security group 'MyAppGroup.' Only problem is, I don't seem able to add this to the search base. User lookup always fails.

Working search base (returns ALL users):

`"ou=Basic Users, ou=BIGAPP Users,dc=subd,dc=domain,dc=com"`

When I asked, they said that MyAppGroup was a security group, and that "Basic Users" and "BIGAPP Users" were "AD Members."

`dsquery group -name "MyAppGroup"`

returns:

`CN=MyAppGroup,OU=BIGAPP Groups,dc=subd,dc=domain,dc=com`

This result does not work as the search base.
Do I need to add a custom search filter for this to work? Any help is appreciated.

---

EDIT: Adding (&(memberOf=BIGAPPS Group)(memberOf=cn=MyAppGroup)) to search filters now returns "LDAP user attributes empty"

---

EDIT 2:
Running the command `dsget group "CN=MyAppGroup,OU=BIGAPP Groups,dc=subd,dc=domain,dc=com" -members -expand` returns a list of group members:

"CN=User McLastname,OU=Basic Users,OU=BIGAPP Groups,dc=subd,dc=domain,dc=com"
"CN=User2 o'Lastname,OU=Basic Users,OU=BIGAPP Groups,dc=subd,dc=domain,dc=com",..etc

So I know the group exists. I feel like I'm missing some small piece to make this work.

EDIT 3:

### settings.py

```py
LDAP_AUTH_URL = "ldap://sub.domain.com"
LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_USERNAME = "django_python3_ldap.utils.format_username_active_directory"

LDAP_AUTH_USE_TLS = True

LDAP_AUTH_ACTIVE_DIRECTORY_DOMAIN = "SUBD"
LDAP_AUTH_SEARCH_BASE="DC=subd,DC=domain,DC=com"
LDAP_AUTH_OBJECT_CLASS="user"
LDAP_AUTH_USER_FIELDS = {
    "username": "sAMAccountName",
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

LDAP_AUTH_FORMAT_SEARCH_FILTERS="myapp.searchfilter.myapp_search_filters"
```

---

Search filters

```py
def myapp_search_filters(ldap_fields):
    search_filters = format_search_filters(ldap_fields)
    search_filters.append("(&(memberOf=cn=MyAppGroup,OU=BIGAPP_Group,DC=subd,DC=domain,dc=com))")
```

Comment: Hmmm, I'm having trouble thinking all of this through. `ou`s are Organizational Units, which I would think `MyAppGroup` would fall under. I'm not sure why they'd try restricting by a `cn`, which is a Common Name.

Comment: I wasn't using the distinguished name for the MyAppGroup in my search filter. LisaJ pointed it out, and I tried it today. Worked like a charm.

Comment: Thanks for popping in, I was running up against a deadline and getting twitchy :o

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the fully qualified DN of the group in the memberOf filter: `(&(memberOf=CN=MyAppGroup,OU=BIGAPP Groups,dc=subd,dc=domain,dc=com))`

Comment: That solved it! Not understanding how distinguished names worked was the problem. I've posted my code up above for other people.